# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

I've searched through many threads and websites looking for this problem. So far, I haven't been able to find anything wrong with this code.

The "bad" code is this: request.AddComment(v, c);

Also, I don't know what a stack trace is.

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Here is my code:

```
string devkey = "1";
string username = "2";
string password = "3";
YouTubeRequestSettings a = 
          new YouTubeRequestSettings("test", devkey, username, password);
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(a);
Uri uri = new Uri("b");
Video v = request.Retrieve<Video>(uri);
Comment c = new Comment();
c.Content = "asdf";
request.AddComment(v, c);
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace or at least the line that is having the problem

Comment: Most probanbly in this line `Video v = request.Retrieve<Video>(uri);` v stays null and on line `request.AddComment(v, c);` the exception is thrown. Can you check that?

Comment: [Breakpoints in Visual-Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k80ex6de.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The only way this snippet might throw a `NullReferenceException` is if `request.Retrieve` returned `null` and `request.AddComment` throws an exception if either parameter is `null`.

The solution is to test `v`:

```
Video v = request.Retrieve<Video>(uri);
if(v != null)
{
    Comment c = new Comment();
    c.Content = "asdf";
    request.AddComment(v, c);
}
else
{
     // something went wrong when getting the video...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Null check the objects that are being referenced. The video request definately should be checked.  Code below does a video null check.

```
string devkey = "1"; 
string username = "2"; 
string password = "3"; 
YouTubeRequestSettings a = new YouTubeRequestSettings("test", devkey, username, password); 
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(a);
    Uri uri = new Uri("b"); 
    Video v = request.Retrieve<Video>(uri); 
    Comment c = new Comment(); 
    c.Content = "asdf"; 
    if (v!= null)
    { 
        request.AddComment(v, c); 
    }
    else
    {
        //Handle the null, try to get the video again, report to user, etc.
    }
```

Comment: `new` _cannot_ return `null`. Testing `request` is unnecessary.

Comment: My bad, Video should be checked. I've updated the code, Thx for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks, so now I know that v returns null :/ Now all I need to do is try and get it to return something else.